# Sleeping thread prevents file writing

Tags: android, multithreading, file, sleep

I am trying to write to a file every 50ms. To do this I sleep a worker thread which then calls the write method from the main thread. Without the sleep it works, without it the file is empty. It doesn't even write the first value (which is written before the thread is slept). Any ideas about this?

Comment: I am just guessing, i do not know android much, but based in my general knowledge: Are you closing the file between writes? you should Open->Write->Close, then the changes will be available. If you do not close the file you have no warranty that the content will be write.

Comment: could you provide us the code? by the way, in the question it's not clear when it works and when the file is empty